# Which version of Padrino runs fine in Ruby 1.8.6?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, rubygems, activesupport, padrino

Padrino 0.10 gem installed activesupprt 3.0.9 which requires ruby >= 1.8.7.

I am Working on Ruby 1.8.6 can any one suggest me which version of Padrino works fine with Ruby 1.8.6 ?

I don't want upgrade Ruby version atleast for 5-6 months. This my current gemfile

```
source :rubygems

# Server requirements
# gem 'thin' or mongrel

# Project requirements
gem 'rake'
gem 'rack-flash'

# Component requirements
#gem 'haml'
gem 'SystemTimer', :require => "system_timer"
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext', :require => "mongo"
gem "state_machine"

# Test requirements
gem 'rspec', :group => "test"
gem 'rack-test', :group => "test", :require => "rack/test"
gem 'mongoid-rspec', :group => "test"

# Padrino
gem 'padrino', '0.10.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v. 0.9.8` should work with ruby 1.8.6.

Comment: This gem has been yanked. I get => Could not find gem 'padrino (= 0.9.8, runtime)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

v. 0.9.9 worked fine for ruby 1.8.6

```
  Installing rake (0.9.2)
  Installing SystemTimer (1.2.3) with native extensions
  Installing activesupport (2.3.5)
  Installing bson (1.0.9)
  Installing bson_ext (1.3.1) with native extensions
  Using bundler (1.0.7)
  Installing diff-lcs (1.1.3)
  Installing durran-validatable (2.0.1)
  Installing fuzzyhash (0.0.11)
  Installing i18n (0.6.0)
  Installing mongo (1.0.9)
  Installing will_paginate (2.3.16)
  Installing mongoid (1.9.0)
  Installing rack (1.3.1)
  Installing tilt (1.3.3)
  Installing sinatra (1.2.6)
  Installing thor (0.14.6)
  Installing usher (0.8.3)
  Installing padrino-core (0.9.9)
  Installing padrino-gen (0.9.9)
  Installing padrino-helpers (0.9.9)
  Installing padrino-admin (0.9.9)
  Installing tmail (1.2.7.1) with native extensions
  Installing padrino-mailer (0.9.9)
  Installing padrino (0.9.9)
  Installing rack-flash (0.1.2)
  Installing rack-test (0.6.0)
  Installing rspec-core (2.6.4)
  Installing rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
  Installing rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
  Installing rspec (2.6.0)
  Installing state_machine (1.0.2)
  Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle_gems
```

I need to set the version of mongoid ~> 1.9.0 and removed mongoid-rspecs as it required active support 3.0, but active support 3.0 required ruby >= 1.8.7